# Raspberry Pi acende o led errado

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Estou a fazer uma expriencia em que acendo um led verde ou um encarnado conforme o resultado de uma pergunta.
Tenho a certeza que o problema não é dos circuitos, pois já tentei de varias formas e acontece sempre o mesmo:
o led que é aceso é sempre o vermelho.
eis o codigo que utilizei:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
def led(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(3)
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
print "How much is 2+2?"
awnser=raw_input(" >")
if awnser==4:
    led(16)
else:
    led(12)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Alguém me pode ajudar?
Obrigado.

Comment: Verificou se não houve confusão entre a configuração de GPIO.BOARD e GPIO.BCM?

Comment: `raw_input` sempre retorna uma string e nunca será igual ao inteiro 4, pois `'4'` é diferente de `4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awnser=raw_input(" >")
if awnser==4:
    led(16)
else:
    led(12)
```

A condição `awnser==4` jamais será satisfeita, pois a função [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fu) **sempre** retorna uma *string* e o Python diferencia `'4'` de `4`.

Você precisará, então, converter o valor para inteiro antes de compará-lo:

```
awnser = int(raw_input('> '))
```

Só tome cuidado que será lançado uma exceção `ValueError` caso o valor informado pelo usuário não possa ser convertido para inteiro, tal como uma letra, por exemplo.